# Alter the table inserted value

Tags: php, sql

disease_category

```
cat_id      cat_name            sub_id          sub_name 

1         Infect Disease           1             head   
1         Infect Disease           2            development de
```

how to alter the `sub_name` development de into development delay?

how to insert new column `C_id` as `primary key` & `auto_increment`?

Comment: You want to insert C_id in your database table ? @praba

Comment: C_id in above table as primary key

Comment: Your question is not clear man. you can use `update` from `mysqli_*` and adding a column to your table. like this `$qry = "ALTER IGNORE TABLE {$table} ADD {$column} VARCHAR(20);"` or whatever you want to alter

Answer (score 1):

how to alter the sub_name development de into development delay?

**Answer**:You need to use update query.

```
update tablename
set sub_name='development delay'
where sub_name='development de'
```

2nd question:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD c_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.